# MongoDB shell installation

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongo-shell

I am trying to install the MongoDB shell.

1. I downloaded the MongoDB Community Server (https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community)
2. I put the downloaded files in the home directory
3. I added the following code to my .bash_profile file:

```
#Path for mongodb 
export PATH=$PATH"~/mongodb-osx-x86_64-enterprise-4.0.10/bin:$PATH"
```

4. Next, I run source ~/.bash_profile in the terminal
5. Then I run  `mongo --nodb` in the terminal, but it returned the error `-bash: mongo: command not found`. Do you have any idea of how to fix the error/ install MongoDB shell in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/mongodb-osx-x86_64-enterprise-4.0.10/bin"
```